# xtext generator how to prevent file override

Tags: java, eclipse, code-generation, xtext, xtend

How do I prevent Xtext generator from overriding custom modification I'm using the method `doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess fsa)` but each time the file gets overridden, I've tried `@Generated NOT` but this didn't work.
thank you

Comment: I have tried to use jdt compare tool but I'm looking my be for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the generator does not use JMerge

you can change the `OutputConfiguration` through `IOutputConfigurationProvider` to set the property `overrideExistingResources`to false (for the default output configuration)

never the less you should consider to adapt the generation gap pattern anyway.